# Can access internet from "Try Ubuntu" but not after "Install Ubuntu"

Tags: networking, unity, internet

New Linux user, downloaded 14.04, got the desktop, selected the "Try Ubuntu", all worked including connect to internet with FireFox.

clicking on the up/down arrows in upper right corner, than clicking on Connection information showed info that I would expect (all looked correct) `ifconfig` showed `eth0`, `lo` and `wlan0`

I Shutdown, restarted, this time selected "Install Ububtu".

All seemed to go well (answered the questions, files being copied, ... the up/down arrows showed in upper right).

Got the `"Installation Complete, need to restart"`.

Restarted and while entering password, got message `"Disconnected - you are now offline"`.

FireFox can't connect to internet. Clicking on the slice of pie shaped icon in upper right says No network device available, and no Configuration Information.  (I can repeat the process - the "Try Ubuntu" option and FireFox works.

How do I get the Install to be able to access the internet?

I also tried Installing from the desktop icon when using the "Try Ubuntu" with the same results.

I have the ability to access the internet by either via ethernet cable or wireless.  I've tried to access with either without success.  I'd be happy to be able to access with either method.

Comment: While I can't help you much with this technically, I am quite sure that anyone trying to help you will want to know: are you primarily trying to access the internet by network cable or by wireless?